# i want to create a dropdownbox(day month year) instead of the inputbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a dropdownbox (day month year) instead of the inputbox. when entered, the selected list will show what date is selected

```html
<style>
form{
 border:1px solid black;
 width:300px;
 padding:5px;
}
.formTitle{
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
<script>
var listForms = []
function createForm(targetID){
 listForms.push(new form(listForms.length)); 
 targetID.appendChild(listForms[listForms.length-1].form);
}

var form = function(formID){
 this.form = document.createElement("form")
 this.form.id = "form"+formID
 this.titleDiv = document.createElement("div")
 this.titleDiv.innerHTML = this.form.id
 this.titleDiv.setAttribute("class","formTitle")
 this.form.appendChild(this.titleDiv)

 this.inputboxList = [];
 this.inputbox = document.createElement("input")
 this.inputbox.type = "text"
 this.inputbox.id = this.form.id + "inputbox" + this.inputboxList.length
 this.inputboxList.push(this.inputbox)
 this.form.appendChild(this.inputbox)

 this.buttonList = [];
 this.button = new button(this.buttonList.length,this);
 this.buttonList.push(this.button.button);
 this.form.appendChild(this.buttonList[this.buttonList.length-1])

}

var button = function(buttonID,parent){
 var parent = parent
 this.button = document.createElement("input")
 this.button.type = "button"
 this.button.value = "button for " + parent.form.id;
 this.button.onclick = function(){
  var inputboxBind = parent.inputboxList[parent.inputboxList.length-1]
  this.button = new button(parent.buttonList.length,parent);
  parent.buttonList.push(this.button.button); 
  var inputbox = document.createElement("input")
  inputbox.type = "text"
  inputbox.id = parent.form.id +  "inputbox" + parent.inputboxList.length
  parent.inputboxList.push(inputbox)
  parent.form.appendChild(inputbox)
  parent.form.appendChild(parent.buttonList[parent.buttonList.length-1])
  alert(inputboxBind.value)
 }
}
</script>

<input id="btnFormCreator" type="button" value="Create a Form">
<div id="targetContainer"></div>

<script>
var targetContainer = document.getElementById("targetContainer");
var btnFormCreator = document.getElementById("btnFormCreator");
btnFormCreator.onclick = function(){
 createForm(targetContainer); 
}
</script>
```

I want to create a dropdownbox (day/month/year) instead of the inputbox.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i dont know how to change the input box with dropdown list that have day/month/year

Comment: You want to remove the input and create a dropdown instead?

Comment: yes sir,with day/month/year dropdown list

Comment: But, what have you tried?

Comment: nothing sir im just new in javascripting and dont know where to insert the codes

Comment: Ahh, well any script must be between `<script>` and `</script>` so you got that. I suggest following [this course](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript) to get a basic understanding of the things you'll need :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your code:

```
this.inputbox.type = "text"
```

to this:

```
this.inputbox.type = "date"
```

And then add the code to format the date:

```
var mydate = new Date(inputboxBind.value);
alert(mydate.getDate() + "/" + mydate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + mydate.getFullYear());
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jxwaoLre/1/)

HTML5 now supports `input` type=`date`, which gives you a drop-down date control rather than a normal textbox.

Comment: thanks sir! this answer is right to the point. can i ask another question because when the alert box appear the date is reverse and start with year

Comment: @Christian You have to manually format the date. I updated the answer :)